# Proving the exponential mean of a negative order <= the geometric mean is less than or equal to the exponential mean of a positive ordet

Tags: analysis

[image][image]![enter image description here]
As said in the title I have to show IF alpha <0 and beta >0 THEN the exponential mean of order (alpha) of a collection of numbers is less or equal to the the geometric mean is less than or equal to exponential mean of order (beta)

Edited to add proof of second part.

I have 1 other question like this this and a couple that I actually have some more usable ideas to go off of.

This is for a final but I assure you we are allowed any resources we want. The style of teaching seems suprising but he seems to know what he's doing. He didn't even bother to mention we make sure we completely understand the proof but I suppose it goes without saying.

I have hours and hours of unusable rabbit holes but no starting idea worth posting on this one yet. Will add to thread if I bring one into existence.[image]

Comment: I think I got the second part trying to upload picture

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I got this. Or professor said it was not meant to be solved creatively at our level. But I got it ! 
 Still needs something dots and crosses alpha is negative better is positive.

That is assuming I can use concavity of log (x) without proving it.[image][image]

Edit I wrote  less than or equal sign backwards in step i
Also should have cited Jensen's discrete inequality along with concavity